# Synonym 'Applications' refers to an invalid object

Tags: sql-database, session-state

After adding SQL Server private sessions storage I get this error:

```
Synonym 'Applications' refers to an invalid object
```

Here is the relevant web.config section:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="mssql" cookieless="false" timeout="20">
    <providers>
        <add name="mssql" type=" Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" sessionType="private" />
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

**UPDATE**

After changing to using SQL Session as per Sitecore's Instructions, I received the error. The only difference between the site working and not working was the above config change. As soon as I made the change and loaded the site, I got the YSOD with the error.

Comment: can you try to restart sql server and run boost sql script again?

Comment: can you check if tempDB is created on sql server

Comment: Ethan, take a look at this post I wrote, it includes some info on testing tempdb and the setup steps: http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/auto-maintaining-sitecore-session-state-permissions-in-tempdb-after-sql-server-restarts/

Answer (score 1):

This came down to permissions. I could not find anything about this in the Sitecore Installation Guide, but my SQL login needed access to the tempdb in order to run the session boost scripts or use the session dbs.